# Login de Acesso

Tags: php, cookies

Gostaria que apenas eu tivesse acesso a `dashboard` da minha página (http://hugovales.esy.es/singin), criei uma página de login mas não sei como permitir apenas o meu acesso.

Gostaria de utilizar um `COOKIE` para isso, criado apenas quando fosse inserido meu email e senha. Caso contrário, o usuário seria redirecionado novamente à página de login.

Aqui está o código do meu formulário:

```
<form class="loginform">
    <input type="text" style="background-color: #fff; border-radius: 3px; padding: 17px 20px; border: none; width: 220px; margin-top: 10px;" name="email" class="mail" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required="">
    <input type="password" style="background-color: #fff; border-radius: 3px; padding: 17px 20px; border: none; width: 220px; margin-top: 10px;" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <input style="padding: 15px 50px; margin-left: 60px;" type="submit" class="login" onclick="alert('Login failed. Check if you typed something wrong or used capital letters in your password. You may have left a field blank.')" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código html do seu formulário? Vai facilitar as coisas.

Comment: Coloquei abaixo, em uma resposta á pergunta.

Comment: Amigo, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código nela, não em uma resposta. Preciso do código do seu formulário para ver o nome dos campos, etc.

Comment: Desculpe. Eu Sou novo por aqui :/

Comment: Relaxa, Hugo! Sem problemas, apenas estou lhe falando isso para sua pergunta ser bem avaliada e para facilitar a leitura, do jeito que está, sua pergunta pode ser fechada ou você receber pontos negativos.

Comment: Consertei a pergunta :) Obrigado. Eu não sabia disso.

Answer (score 7):

Bom amigo, primeiro o que você precisa entender é o que um cookie é, vamos lá.

**O que é um cookie?** Tecnicamente falando, um cookie é um conjunto de informações que fica armazenada na máquina do usuário, dessa forma ele pode, por exemplo, adicionar produtos a um carrinho de compra, digitar seu login e senha apenas uma vez e ser lembrado por um tempo, isso porque cada cookie tem um prazo de validade.

Recomendo a leitura dessa matéria: [Diferenças entre Cookies e Sessões](http://klauslaube.com.br/2012/04/05/entendendo-os-cookies-e-sessoes.html), você pediu um cookie, mas é importante saber o que é uma sessão também.

Então, colocando o foco no seu sistema, o cookie não irá fazer SÓ VOCÊ acessar o sistema, e sim será criado com as informações que você definir e num momento futuro, permitir o acesso sem que você tenha que digitar seu email e senha novamente, lembrando, somente na mesma máquina.

Como o código que você tem até agora é apenas html, me dei a liberdade de criar os códigos `javascript/jquery` e `php`.

Primeiro peguei todo o [`css inline`](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/insetut.php) do seu formulário e coloquei dentro da tag `<style>` (para melhor visualização e organização). Com isso, o código do seu `form` ficou assim:

```
<form id="login-form" class="loginform">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-field" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" class="input-submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Bem melhor, não? Agora o seu código css:

```
<style>
    .input-field {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 17px 20px;
        border: none;
        width: 220px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .input-submit {
        padding: 15px 50px;
        margin-left: 60px;
    }
</style>
```

Vamos para nosso código `javascript`, eu costumo sempre enviar meus formulários por ajax (nesse exemplo vou fazer assim), mas o uso dele não é necessário. Para isso você precisa ter incluído no seu site o [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login-form').submit(function() {
            // Capturamos o evento de submit do formulário
            // e impedimos que ele sejá concluído.
            e.preventDefault();

            var mail = $('#email').val(),
                pass = $('#password').val();

            // Coloque as validações dos campos aqui, se houver.

            $.ajax({
                url: 'sua_pagina.php',  // Essa página receberá os dados do javascript e fará as validações e criará o cookie
                data: $('#login-form').serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if (data == 'logged') {
                    windows.location.href = 'dashboard.php';
                } else if (data == 'login failed') {
                    alert('Email ou senha incorretos.');
                }
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Explicando:** vamos enviar os dados do seu formulário para a página `sua_pagina.php`, ela irá receber os dados, fazer as validações e consequentemente criar o cookie ou então, retornar erro de preenchimento. O formulário está sendo enviado por `POST`.

Agora, segue o código da `sua_pagina.php`:

```
<?php

$mail = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

// Parte de validações dos valores
// [...]

// Parte em que você recupera os valores corretos do banco
// Como você não disse se tem uma tabela para usuário ou não
// e sim "exatamente meu email e senha" vamos declarar no código mesmo
// porém NUNCA FAÇA ISSO!!
$meu_email   = "hugo.marcelo@dominio.com.br";
$minha_senha = "asdfasdf123123asdsd123123";

// Recomendo utilizar hash para armazenar e verificar sua senha
// http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php
if ( $mail == $meu_email && $pass == $minha_senha ) {

    // A função time() retorna a hora atual medida
    // no número de segundos desde 1 de janeiro de 1970 (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php)
    // Nesse caso, definimos o cookie com um prazo de expiração de 30 dias.
    // Documentação da função setcookie(): http://php.net/setcookie
    setcookie( "email", $mail, ( time() + (30 * 24 * 3600) ) );
    setcookie( "pass", $pass, ( time() + (30 * 24 * 3600) ) );

    echo "logged";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "login failed";
    exit();
}
```

Caso os dados inseridos no formulário estejam corretos, seremos redirecionados para a página `dashboard.php`, e no início do código dela e de todas as páginas que você deseja proteger **deveremos** verificar se o cookie existe:

```
<?php
    if ( !isset($_COOKIE["email"]) && !isset($_COOKIE["pass"]) ) {
        header("Location: signin.php");
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu irei testar. Espero que funcione. Desde já agradeço por tirar do seu tempo para me ajudar.

Comment: Não Funcionou, Mesmo assim obrigado. Eu segui todos os passos, mas não consegui. Usei o JQuery, e o PHP, tudo direitinho, mas não consegui :\

Comment: A Resposta do @Eduardo Silva está com tudo que você precisa, pode explicar o que ocorreu que não deu certo?

Comment: Eu usei o código, mas quando eu vou logar não funcionou. Mesmo assim, eu  o agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma alternativa e mais simples (julgo eu) seria utilizar session de PHP:

```
session_start();
if((!isset($_SESSION['email']) == true) and (!isset($_SESSION['pass']) == true)){
        require_once 'components/modals/login-modal.php';
        require_once 'components/modals/create-account-modal.php';
    }else{
        require_once 'components/modals/logout-modal.php';
    }
```

Explicando: Eu dividi minha pagina em pequenos arquivos php (com elementos HTML puro) e verifico se o usuário esta logado se sim a página será composta com um botão logout caso não com botões login e cadastro.